# ssh asking for a password but not accepting it

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine

I'm trying to `scp` through a virtual machine but when the guest terminal asks for my host user password it simply does not accept my real user password. Is the machine asking for another entry?

The user is not root and I know it's password in the host machine
it looks like this:

```
user@host's password:
Permission denied, please try again:
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91499/discussion-on-question-by-mranon-ssh-asking-for-a-password-but-not-accepting-it).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from above mentioned points, you need to consider another 2 files in remote server which you are connecting:

```
/etc/hosts.allow
/etc/hosts.deny
```

You need to check whether your ssh connection is allowed or not from the server which you are connecting to.

Format:

```
daemon:ACCESS 
daemon can be vsftpd,sshd
```

if you want to allow only for particular network, put below entry in `/etc/hosts.allow`:

```
sshd:192.168.159.*
```

(The above means that an ssh connection is allowed for network 192.168.159.*)

If you want to restrict for a particular network, put below entry in `/etc/hosts.deny`:

```
sshd:192.168.139.*
```

(The above means that an ssh connection is not allowed for network 192.168.139.*)