# SSH not accepting the correct passwords

Tags: debian, ssh, openssh, debian-installer

I installed Debian 10 on a second drive inside my main pc, the installer gave me the option of installing SSH, which I did. I checked the drive booted still on my main pc which it did (and I was able to log in via my username and password, which worked as expected). I then put it in another computer with no display connected, and tried to ssh in to it. However, SSH comes back saying :

```
permission denied, please try again
Connection to 192.168.1.251 closed
```

I have tried many online guides including here: [ssh asking for a password but not accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508349/ssh-asking-for-a-password-but-not-accepting-it) to no avail, as well as checking my ssh.conf and sshd.conf files, restarting and manually reinstalling the ssh server (all done on the first pc as that has a display)

If you need more verbose output to this, I can provide; writing on a mobile device at the moment so I can’t paste it easily.

Comment: try after disabling selinux and firewall

Comment: and check sshd service is running

Comment: I am confused as well. Did you ever try to ssh when it was in the 1st machine? (is the difference 1st machine vs 2nd machine?, or is it graphical login vs `ssh`?)

Comment: Are you trying to log in as root or a different user?

Comment: Icarus, I’m logging in as the default user (Jeremy in my case) but root doesn’t work either.

Comment: msp9011, neither SELinux nor Firewall are enabled as this is a fresh install

Comment: Ctrl-alt-delor I did also try ssh when the disk was in the first machine, and it also didn’t work

Comment: You're saying that the same installation works in one computer but when the disk is moved to a second chassis it stops working? Are you sure you are really connecting to the correct machine?

Comment: Can you log in on the console? What does `/var/log/auth.log` tell you about the failed logins?

Comment: Roaima, I’m sorry if it wasn’t clear, the ssh login doesn’t work inside both chassis. The auth.log file does not appear to display anything about the ssh logins, there is nothing in between the 2 times I used sudo to open the auth.log file.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "_I was able to log in via my username and password_" if you mean you couldn't log in?